# Some logic in Doctrine2 Entity

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

in my User entity I have some field, that is responsible for the likes of some user for some post:

```
/**
     * @var ArrayCollection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Post")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="posts_likes",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="post_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")}
     * )
     **/
    protected $postsLikes;
```

The question is: is it normal to have methods below in entity:

```
/**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getPostsLikesIds()
    {
        $ids = [];

        if ($this->postsLikes) {
            var_dump($this->postsLikes);
            foreach ($this->postsLikes as $postLike) {
                $ids[] = $postLike->getId();
            }
        }

        return $ids;
    }

    /**
     * @param $postId
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isPostLiked($postId)
    {
        return in_array($postId, $this->getPostsLikesIds());
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The magic word here is **"responsible"**.

Keep in mind that `Doctrine` is just a library that helps you with the persistence. It **must not** affect your business logic. Ignore the persistence and ask yourself: *"Who's responsible for managing the user likes?"* The answer tells you exactly where to put the code that handles them.

To be more precise, the listed methods are tied to the `$postsLikes` property of class `User`. Don't you dare to move them in a different class.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Just to add, http://ocramius.github.io/doctrine-best-practices/#/35 - useful stuff here.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason why should not have methods in your entities. In your particular case, it is the way to go.